# If $f$ is continuous, so is $f(x^3)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f:R\rightarrow R$ is differentiable and define $g(x)=x^2 f(x^3)$. Show $g$ is differentiable and compute $g'$.

So I know how to do the proof, I just want to know that even though $f$ is continuous why would $f(x^3)$ be continuous?

Comment: What do you think the composition of two continuous functions is?

Comment: Thank you for providing context. But please put your actual *question* in the title -- not the problem that gave rise to it. Otherwise, people will get confused. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $g: x \to x^3$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

With $h(x) = x^3$, $f(x^3) = f(h(x))$.  It is a theorem that the composition of two continuous functions is continuous.